# Google Maps Marker is not below the InfoWindow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, google-maps, google-api

So my Google Maps API marker is constantly being hidden by my infowindow and I'm not sure how to position the infowindow so that it is above the marker on my google map. I've tried using css before but it wouldn't move the infowindow nor the marker anywhere.

here's my Map.js file code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  GoogleMap,
  useLoadScript,
  Marker,
  InfoWindow,
} from "@react-google-maps/api";

function Map() {
  const { isLoaded } = useLoadScript({
    googleMapsApiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY,
  });

  const location = { lat: -33.81724, lng: 150.99908 };
  const [selectedMarker, setSelectedMarker] = useState(null);

  if (!isLoaded) return <div>Loading...</div>;

  const handleMarkerClick = (marker) => {
    setSelectedMarker(marker);
  };

  return (
    <GoogleMap
      zoom={20}
      center={{ lat: location.lat, lng: location.lng }}
      mapContainerStyle={{
        position: "relative",
        top: 50,
        right: 290,
        width: "230%",
        height: "30vh",
      }}
    >
      <Marker position={location} onClick={() => handleMarkerClick(location)} />
      {selectedMarker && (
        <InfoWindow
          position={selectedMarker}
          anchor={{
            x: 0,
            y: -40,
          }}
          onCloseClick={() => setSelectedMarker(null)}
        >
          <div>
            <h3>ABAD & VILLANUEVA SOLICITOR'S</h3>
          </div>
        </InfoWindow>
      )}
    </GoogleMap>
  );
}

export default Map;
```

Answer (score 0):

### `<InfoWindow />` Component should be a child of the `<Marker></Marker>` Component

Marker component section of your code:

```
  <Marker position={location} onClick={() => handleMarkerClick(location)} />
  {selectedMarker && (
    <InfoWindow
      position={selectedMarker}
      anchor={{
        x: 0,
        y: -40,
      }}
      onCloseClick={() => setSelectedMarker(null)}
    >
      <div>
        <h3>ABAD & VILLANUEVA SOLICITOR'S</h3>
      </div>
    </InfoWindow>
  )}
```

Notice that you have made the `<Marker>` component as self closing with the `/` at the end. That means that the `<InfoWindow>` became a separate entity itself instead of being within the `<Marker>` component. Which explains why it looked like it is trying to overlap the marker.

[image]

To fix this, you just have to enclose the `<InfoWindow>` component within the `<Marker>` component, like so:

```
    {/* Change your marker into a non self-closing */}
    <Marker position={location} onClick={() => handleMarkerClick(location)}>
      {selectedMarker && (
        <InfoWindow
          position={selectedMarker}
          anchor={{
            x: 0,
            y: -40
          }}
          onCloseClick={() => setSelectedMarker(null)}
        >
          <div>
            <h3>ABAD & VILLANUEVA SOLICITOR'S</h3>
          </div>
        </InfoWindow>
      )}
      {/* Close the Marker component here to enclose the <InfoWindow />
      Component as a child of the Marker component, and things should
      work fine! */}
    </Marker>
```

After making the changes, it should look something like this:

[image]

Here's a proof of concept snippet if you want to check it out yourself: https://codesandbox.io/s/answer-google-maps-marker-is-not-below-the-infowindow-ub458b?file=/src/Map.js

Hope this helps!